Selective data loading from SSD Storage into system RAM
I want to store a data file on the SSD so that I could selectively pick and bring any specific subset of that whole data. Also, FYI: the data is stored as a hashmap.
Basically, the file is huge enough that it won't accommodate in the system memory (RAM) all at once. So that is why I only want to load the data corresponding to specific keys that I require at a time. Is is possible to only load few key value pairs from this hashmap data structure from within SSD itself so that only these selected data values are brought to the RAM?
